# Get a Http 400 Bad Request - Invalid Hostname when call a IIS site by IP not by DNS

Tags: http, wcf, dns, iis-10

We have a IIS 10.0 on Windows Server 2016 with many sites.
The binding for each site respect the this convention -> http:*:APort:  (no hostname and no ip address specified)

Everything was working fine until recently (3days).

For each site we have the following problem :

- From the outside of my server, when I call a WCF site by DNS
  (http://mydns.domain:1234) I can access to my site correctly
- From the outside of my server, when I call a WCF site by IP (http://123.45.67.89:1234) I have an error http 400 : Bad Request - Invalid Hostname
- From the inside of my server, when I call a WCF site by localhost
  (http://localhost:1234) I can access to my site correctly
- From the inside of my server, when I call a WCF site by IP (http://127.0.0.1:1234) I have
  an error http 400 : Bad Request - Invalid Hostname

No log in IIS log, but an error in system htterr file
`2020-08-12 09:42:22 XX.XX.XX.XX 43868 123.45.67.89 1234 HTTP/1.0 HEAD / - 400 - Hostname W3SvcInspection`

DNS and SPN Config are OK.

The only way we found to solve the problem is to create a new site with a binding configuration like http:123.45.67.89:aPort:
After IISReset all other sites work fine (the bindings of other sites have not been change).

We have an other server with same configuration and no problem on it.

Comment: Why "HTTP/1.0"?

Comment: I think this is not relevant for the question, we produce a simple case for this post. It still not work in HTTP/1.1 or HTTPS.

Comment: About WCF services hosted in IIS, you can refer to this link:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-host-a-wcf-service-in-iis

Comment: Thank you @DingPeng but we don't have any problem for hosting WCF services in IIS...

Comment: This may be a problem with IIS, you can try self-hosting.